# Counterexample to Fubini?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to come up with a measurable function on $[0,1]^2$ which is not integrable, but such that the iterated integrals are defined and unequal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the double integrals
$$I:=\int_0^1\int_0^1{y-x\over(2-x-y)^3}\ dy\ dx\ ,\qquad
J:=\int_0^1\int_0^1{y-x\over(2-x-y)^3}\ dx\ dy\ .$$
Then
$$\int_0^1{y-x\over(2-x-y)^3}\ dy={y-1\over(2-x-y)^2}\Biggr|_{y=0}^1={1\over(2-x)^2}\ .$$
It follows that
$$I=\int_0^1 {dx\over(2-x)^2}={1\over 2-x}\Biggr|_0^1={1\over2}\ .$$
Similarly you get $J=-{1\over2}\ne I$.

Comment: How do you show that $\int_0^1\int_0^1 | {y-x\over(2-x-y)^3 }\ | dx\ dy\ < \infty$ ? Is there any obvious way that doesn't require much calculations?

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \,dy\,dx \ne \int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \,dx\,dy
$$

Obviously either of these is $-1$ times the other and if this function were absolutely integrable, then they would be equal, so their value would be $0$.  But one is $\pi/2$ and the other is $-\pi/2$, as may be checked by freshman calculus methods.

Comment: It is not $\pm\frac\pi2$ but $\pm\frac\pi4$: 
$$\int_0^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}~\mathrm dy=\left[\frac y{x^2+y^2}\right]_0^1=\frac1{1+x^2}$$ and
$$\int_0^1\frac1{1+x^2}~\mathrm dx=\left[\arctan x\right]_0^1=\frac\pi4.$$