# Find $f(x,y)$ such that $\int\int f(x,y)dxdy \neq \int\int f(x,y)dydx$ how can this be?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

The question is: find a function $f: [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} f(x,y)dxdy \neq \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} f(x,y) dydx$ and both integrals exist.

I'm not saying that it's impossible, if  that's the question then it certainly is possible. but I don't understand how such a function can exist. We are integrating over the same area, how can the integrals be different?

Doesn't this defy Fubini's Theorem?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem

Rather than just giving me an example of such a function, I'd like to understand why such a situation is possible.

Edit: A friend just told me that he had just found such a function, $\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ , but how come Fubini's theorem doesnt hold for this function?

Comment: Look carefully at the assumptions of Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Already answered: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258465/iterated-integrals-counterexample-to-fubinis-theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Counterexamples" to Fubini:
[Counterexample to Fubini?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253921/counterexample-to-fubini),
http://www.math.jhu.edu/~jmb/note/nofub.pdf,
http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m226/fubini.pdf.