# To show that two repeated integrals are equal

Tags: integration

Suppose $0<h<1$.

To show that if $f(x,y)=\frac{y^2-x^2}{(y^2+x^2)^2}$, then the repeated integral, $$\int_h^1 {\Large\lbrace} \int_h^1 f(x,y) dx {\Large\rbrace}dy=\int_h^1{\Large\lbrace}\int_h^1 f(x,y) dy {\Large\rbrace}dx $$

but they are not equal if $h=0$.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I have no time to check but I would consider the two integrals as functions of $h$ and show they have the same derivative (via the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus). They are obviously equal when $h=1$.

Comment: Does the first answer of the following post answer your question for "not equal if $h=0$"? [Counterexample to Fubini?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253921/counterexample-to-fubini) (equality for $0<h<1$ comes directly from Fubini's theorem).

Comment: @AnneBauval Ok if got it now if $h\neq 0$. But for $h=0$, i still find it difficult.

Comment: I added a comment to Michael Hardy's answer in that post

Comment: @AnneBauval I got it now. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. Will you vote for closing?